# Getting multiple options for the same file when I click run

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij and creating a web application. It is working fine but whenever I try to run the app on a browser, I get multiple options for the same file as show in the image below. When I update something on home.html and run any of the options in the image, I get the updated results.

So why am I getting so many options? Shouldn't it be just one? Is it some configuration issues? Day one, when I first run the app, I only had 1 option. Ever since then, I been getting multiples. Also, I have probably run it like a 100 times or more but as you can see, I do not have a 100 options.

Tried to restart the IDE and even restart the PC and it is still the same. Please advice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click `Edit configurations...` in the list
2. A new window pops up
3. On the left, select `home.html (1)`
4. Click the minus button on the top (2nd from left)
5. Repeat for other unnecessary `home.html (X)` run configs

Comment: That does clear up the list, but when I run it, the list starts to populate with multiple duplicates again. Any way to prevent this from occurring permanently? Not even sure whats the point of having duplicates.

Comment: @JasSy Probably it's an IntelliJ bug (or not well-designed behaviour). If you click the green run icon on the right side of the list, it won't add new run configs.